# TNS-03505 - ORACLE tnsping

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Ao tentar pingar, usando o `tnsping`.

ex: `tnsping UMEXEMPLO`

Me aparece o seguinte erro

> **TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name**

Qual solução normalmente se aplica?

**EDIT:**

De outras maquinas acessamos normalmente ao Banco no servidor. O `service name` esta configurado conforme o servidor, as variáveis de ambiente também, quando pingamos ele recebe os saltos com sucesso mas, quando pingamos direto no servidor onde esta o Banco, da o erro informado.

Answer (score 2):

Você já verificou o `TNSNAMES`?
Ele fica no caminho:

> **[seuDiretório]\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora**

O erro **TNS-03505** siginifica que houve uma falha para resolver o nome ou `SERVICE_NAME`.

Segue abaixo um exemplo de conexão de entrada:

```
BDTESTE = 
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.200)(PORT = 12346))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SERVICE_NAME = bdteste.xyz.com.br)
    )
  )
```

1. Verifique no arquivo se o `Service Name` que informou existe.
2. Ainda no `TNSNAMES.ORA`, verifique se o `SERVICE_NAME` está correto.
3. Salve o arquivo e faça o ping novamente: `tnsping BDTESTE`

#### Útilidade

Para verificar o service name de um BD use o comando abaixo:

```
select value from v$parameter where name like '%service_name%';
```

#### Verifique também o SQLNET.ORA

Se estiver usando o nome local (arquivo `tnsnames.ora`) verifique se `TNSNAMES` está listado como um dos valores do parâmetro `NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH` no perfil do Oracle Net (arquivo `sqlnet.ora`). Exemplo SQLNET.ORA:

```
# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

O arquivo `SQLNET.ORA` fica no mesmo local do `TNSNAMES` informado acima.

Comment: Sim, já foi verificado tanto o TSNAMES, quanto as variáveis de ambiente, e o erro persiste.

Comment: Você tem acesso a essa base de alguma outra forma? De outro computador? Executou o comando pra verificar o service_name? Nos mostre como ele está, com mais detalhes ficará mais fácil te ajudar.

Comment: Sim, de outras maquinas acessamos normalmente ao Banco no servidor.    O service name esta configurado conforme o servidor, as variáveis de ambiente também, quando pingamos ex. ping xxx.xx.x.xxx ele recebe os saltos com sucesso, quando pingamos direto na base de dados, da erro TNS-03505

Comment: Direto da base? No próprio servidor do BD ou em alguma máquina configurada para acesso a ele?

Comment: RETIFICANDO - Sim, de outras maquinas acessamos normalmente ao Banco no servidor.    O service name esta configurado conforme o servidor, as variáveis de ambiente também, quando pingamos ex. ping xxx.xx.x.xxx ele recebe os saltos com sucesso, quando pingamos direto no servidor onde esta o Banco, da erro TNS-03505

Comment: Veja o conteúdo que adicionei com a edição se resolve o problema.