# Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados oracle usando programação web em .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, oracle, webforms

Ao realizar tentativas de conexão com o banco obtive o erro de acordo com a imagem em anexo.
Minha aplicação é web em .net, visual studio 2010, banco de dados oracle sql developed 3.1.07.

Meu código onde apresenta o erro:

```
protected int GetRowCounts()
    {
        int iRowCount = 0;


        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=DAPP;PASSWORD=APL_SD7#PP4;USER ID=APL_SDP"))
        {
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select count(*) from SDPJ_IMPORT_PROCESSO", conn);
            conn.Open();

            // Executa o SqlCommand e obtendo as contagens da linhas.
            iRowCount = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }

        return iRowCount;
    }
```

[image: Erro]

Comment: [Essa resposta talvez ajude](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203333/tns-03505-oracle-tnsping/203350#203350)

Comment: Apenas corrigindo :D você escreveu **dot.net**, mas não faz sentido. É **dotNet** ou **.Net**, afinal **dot** é **ponto** em inglês. Se você escreve **dot.net** seria o mesmo que **dotdotnet** ou **..net**.

Answer (score 2):

Verifique no diretório

> C:\app\product\11.1.0\client_1\network\admin

e procure pelo arquivo **tnsnames.ora**, dentro desse arquivo vai estar as configurações de acesso a base de dados. Ele carrega essas configurações para fazer o acesso a base de dados, se algum dado estiver errado, ele não consegue carregar essas informações e dispara o erro que você informou.

Answer (score 0):

Esse método `GetRowCounts()` está com acesso protegido. O que significa que ele só irá executar dentro da própria classe. Se você estiver tentando executá-lo em outra classe, então você precisa mudar o acesso do método para **public** ou criar um método de acesso **public** na mesma classe do `GetRowCounts()`, chamá-lo dentro desse novo método e executar o novo método no lugar onde deseja.

Comment: realizei a alteração conforme vc me sugeriu, porém voltou com o seguinte erro: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified. O erro acontece nesse código:  public int GetRowCounts()
        {int iRowCount = 0;
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=DAPP;PASSWORD=APL_SD7#PP4;USER ID=APL_SDP"))
            {
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select count(*) from SDPJ_IMPORT_PROCESSO", conn);
                conn.Open(); iRowCount = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }return iRowCount;
        }

Comment: Faz o que o Wagner Barbosa Do Nascimento sugeriu. Ao que parece, o erro de conexão persiste por causa de algum dado inválido. Verifica se o host, nome do banco, usuário e senha estão corretos. Mas mantém aquele procedimento que eu te falei, caso contrário, o método não será executado se estiver protegido e você tentar chamá-lo fora da sua classe.

Comment: Opa pessoal, obritado pelas dicas, resolvi meu problema, muito obrigado mesmo, postei uma outra duvida, caso alguém puder me ajudar